# How to hide a div on page load which is in another php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a php file where I include multiple php files and their respective javascript files.

In the ajax `.done(function(){ })` I reload my main page which includes all the other files. So is there any way to hide the div which is inside another php page?

**code:**

```
.done(function (msg) {
     $('#abc').load('list.php').fadeIn("slow");
});
```

`list.php` is the main file. Help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$("#page1").hide()`. And then when you're ready `$("#page1").show()`

Alternatively using a CSS class with `display: none` and then removing the class or using `$("#page1").toggleClass("anotherclass")` to switch between a second class.